# In the Parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus, does listening to Moses and the prophets guarantee a place of comfort after death?

Tags: moses, jews

> But Abraham said, 'They have Moses and the prophets; they must respond to them.' NET  Luke 16:29

Thus, the prophets complement Moses for the Jews to save themselves.

Comment: There is only one name whereby we must be saved - "Jesus", Acts 4:12.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the tabernacled (incarnate) logos/divine verb is the only one.

Comment: John 1:45; also > How can you believe, when you receive glory from one another and do not seek the glory that comes from the only God? 45 Do not think that I will accuse you to the Father. There is one who accuses you: Moses, on whom you have set your hope. 46 For if you believed Moses, you would believe me; for he wrote of me. 47 But if you do not believe his writings, how will you believe my words?” 
 (John 5:44–47, ESV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let extent a few more verses. Luke 16:29-31 read

> 29 But Abraham said, ‘They have Moses and the prophets; they must respond to them.’
>
> 30 Then the rich man said, ‘No, father Abraham, but if someone from the dead goes to them, they will repent.’
>
> 31 He replied to him, ‘If they do not respond to Moses and the prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead.’” (NET)

Moses and the prophets represent the law. The parable was saying if they did not obey the law, even they saw Jesus risen from the dead, they still did not repent.

The title question using "listening" is not accurate. "response to" means "obey". So only listen to Moses and the prophets does not guarantee salvation, it has to obey 100%. James 2:10 read

> 10 For whosoever shall keep the whole law, and yet offend in one point, he is guilty of all.

It is hardly one can obey the law completely.

Paul wrote in Romans 3:20-24, that no one can declare his righteousness by the deeds of the law, and therefore we need Jesus' redemption.

> 20 **Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall no flesh be justified in his sight**: for by the law is the knowledge of sin.
>
> 21 But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets;
>
> 22 Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that believe: for there is no difference:
>
> 23 For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God;
>
> 24 **Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:** (NET)

Jesus already gave a hint before he told the Parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus. Luke 16:16 read

> 16 “The law and the prophets were in force until John; since then, **the good news of the kingdom of God has been proclaimed**, and everyone is urged to enter it. (NET)

So the enforcement of the law came to an end when Jesus came. It is time to accept Jesus as the Lord and obey to His teaching. This is now the only way to guarantee our salvation.